# Traditional I/O on the client side and NIO in Server. How do I get specific message if the client sends multiple message in the same socket?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, apache-mina

I am using Apache Mina in the *server* side. I've a client which is written in traditional I/O. Here's the *client* side code that sends data to the server.

```
class SomeClass extends Thread
{
    Socket socket;

    // Constructor
    SomeClass()
    {
        Socket socket = ...
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (j++ < 10)
        {
            System.out.println("CLIENT[" + clientNo + "] Send Message =>" + requests[clientNo][j]);
            OutputStream oStrm = socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] byteSendBuffer = (requests[clientNo][j]).getBytes();
            oStrm.write(byteSendBuffer);
            oStrm.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The above thread is run for say 20 times. So 20 sockets are created. And in one socket, many messages are send. With a server written using I/O socket classes I'm able to retrieve data perfectly.

The problem comes in the Apache Mina based server which uses BUFFER! I am not able to get individual messages.

How do I get individual messages (given I’m not able to change anything in the client, *and* the length of individual messages are not known).

**Server-side code**

*Socket Creation*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());
    IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
    ProtocolCodecFilter(charset.newEncoder(), charset.newDecoder()));
    acceptor.setHandler(new TimeServerHandler());
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(64);
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 10);
    acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
}
```

*Handler Code*

```
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {

    AbstractIoBuffer bf = (AbstractIoBuffer)message;
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
    String outString = bf.getString(decoder);
}
```

Comment: Can you please send the crucial part of the server side code? For this question the client side code is of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i get individual messages

You don't. There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It is a byte-stream protocol. There are no message boundaries and there is no guarantee that one read equals one write at the other end.

> (given i'm not able to change anything in client, AND the length of individual messages are not known)

Your are going to have to parse the messages to find where they stop according to the definition of the application protocol. If that isn't possible because, say, the protocol is ambiguous, the client will have to be junked. However it seems that as you can't change the client, it must already work with an existing system, so the guy before you had the same problem and solved it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

MINA is actually a very elaborate framework to solve your problem in an elegant way. Its basic concept is a filter chain, in which a series of filters are applied on an incoming message.

You should implement a protocol decoder (implementing `MessageDecoder`) and register it in your MINA filter chain. That decoder should parse byte buffers to the object representation of your choice.

Then, you can register a message handler that handles complete messages.

Comment: but in my case the buffer contains the contents of more than one message. e.g : Msg1: Hai Tom, Msg2: Hai Peter.. when both are send in the same socket, in the buffer i get BufferMsg:"Hai TomHai Peter". How do i do it in the filters? From what i've read about filters that isn't possible. any help?

Comment: Perhaps you should re-consider your protocol design. Remember that TCP socket is a pipe: on the receiving side, you're getting a stream of bytes without knowing what their intended fragmentation is. Consider using, in your channel, a protocol that will signal the message boundaries. Common ways to do that are to use a separator symbol, such as character '\0' between messages, or a message structure in which you send message length (as byte, short or integer) and then that number of bytes of the message body.

Comment: doesn't out.flush() do what u said?

Comment: Short answer is, sometimes. You can't trust it to do so, because routers (or even the local tcp stack) could merge several messages into one or fragment a long message into several. Bottom line is, a TCP connection is a bidirectional pipe; you can't use anything you see beyond the sequence of bytes you can read.

Comment: (You might want to consider UDP, where a message *is* a message. But then you have to handle packet loss, reordering, etc).